# How does one make a recycler view with two rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an view which has two two columns, is that possible with recycler view?

I was thinking of possibly programically making each row_layout half the width, but that seems incorrect.  Is there a better way?

*edit, sorry i wrote two rows, i meant to write two columns.  Obviously as more items get added more rows will be needed

Comment: use recyclerview with grid layout manager

Comment: there is no need in a RecyclerView, if all rows are supposed to be visible. Use LinearLayout instead

Comment: post your view screen shot

Comment: Think of an e-commerce website, but with two items per row

Comment: Unfortunately i can't post a screen shot as the designs have an NDA and I dont have photoshop so i cant make my own version.

Comment: thanks Akshay Bhat, that was the correct answer, this tutorial has what I need
http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: @AdamKatz Just do a little search before posting basic questions here. They all have answers.

Comment: thanks I had done a bit of googling and somehow missed it, guess next time i will spend more time.  I was sure there must be a simpler answer too :(

Comment: `recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));` you're welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I needed was a grid layout manager, this tutorial has the answer

http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html